# problems in reset button java

Tags: java, user-interface

```
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.util.Random;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;

public class Guess extends JFrame
{
private JLabel l1;
private JLabel l2;
private JTextField t1;
private JButton b[]=new JButton[2];

static Random r1=new Random();
int rand=r1.nextInt(1000)+1;

public Guess()
{
    super("Guess the number game ");
    l1=new JLabel("Guess The number");
    l2=new JLabel(" ");
    t1=new JTextField(5);
    b[0]=new JButton("Check");
    b[1]=new JButton("Reset");

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    add(l1);
    add(t1);


    perform action=new perform();
    resettt reseting=new resettt();
    add(b[0]);
    b[0].addActionListener(action);
    add(b[1]);
    b[1].addActionListener(reseting);
    add(l2);


}

private class perform implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
            String s1=t1.getText();
            int g=Integer.parseInt(s1);


            if(g>rand)
            {
                l2.setText("Too high");
                t1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            }
            else if(g<rand)
            {
                l2.setText("Too low");
                t1.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            else if(g==rand)
            {
                t1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                t1.setEditable(false);
                t1.setText("Correct");
                l2.setText(" ");
            }//end of last if
    }//end of actionPerformed
}//end perform

private class resettt implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
                t1.setText(" ");
                t1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                t1.setEditable(true);
                l2.setText(" ");
                rand=r1.nextInt(1000)+1;


        }
    }

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Guess t=new Guess();
    t.setVisible(true);
    t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    t.setSize(350,100);
    t.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
}
```

now the problem is when i press the reset button it will show me several errors

NB:**The errors are not after building the program, it will show some script in the CMD after clicking the RESET button**

and these are the errors :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at Guess$perform.actionPerformed(Guess.java:47)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
```

Comment: Post those errors resp. the stack trace.

Comment: @ProgrammingIsAwsome the errors are not understood from the CMD not from the code it self

Comment: when you parse your String, you have a error, because, you try to parse: ` 1` string, there is a gape is excess. Just before parse string to integer, write: `s1 = s1.replaceAll(" ", "");`

Comment: Instead of a JTextField, composer using a JSpinner or JFormattedTextField which provides automatic validation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your solution is simple :

exchange `Integer.parseInt(s1);` for `Integer.parseInt(s1.trim());` and maybe add `Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matches(s1)` beforehand.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim():

> public String trim() Returns a copy of the string, with leading and
>   trailing whitespace omitted. If this String object represents an empty
>   character sequence, or the first and last characters of character
>   sequence represented by this String object both have codes greater
>   than '\u0020' (the space character), then a reference to this String
>   object is returned.
>
> Otherwise, if there is no character with a code greater than '\u0020'
>   in the string, then a new String object representing an empty string
>   is created and returned.
>
> Otherwise, let k be the index of the first character in the string
>   whose code is greater than '\u0020', and let m be the index of the
>   last character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020'. A
>   new String object is created, representing the substring of this
>   string that begins with the character at index k and ends with the
>   character at index m-that is, the result of this.substring(k, m+1).
>
> This method may be used to trim whitespace (as defined above) from the
>   beginning and end of a string.
>
> Returns: A copy of this string with leading and trailing white space
>   removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String):

> public boolean matches(String regex) Tells whether or not this string
>   matches the given regular expression. An invocation of this method of
>   the form str.matches(regex) yields exactly the same result as the
>   expression
>
> Pattern.matches(regex, str) Parameters: regex - the regular expression
>   to which this string is to be matched Returns: true if, and only if,
>   this string matches the given regular expression Throws:
>   PatternSyntaxException - if the regular expression's syntax is invalid
>   Since:
>   1.4 See Also: Pattern

Answer (score 1):

This exception was probably not shown when clicking the 'Reset' but when clicking on the 'Check' button **After** a reset and some new input.

The reason for the error is that you do not test that the input in the text field is actualy a number before you try and parse it to `int`. You also set the text of the input text field to a whitespace instead of a blank String `""`, which couses the input to contain a non-number character and fail in parsing.

You should use a text field that filters an integer input only [see an example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Textfieldonlyacceptsnumbers.htm).